# Issue in rotating UIImage - IOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, uiimage, swift-extensions

For rotating an UIImage I used an extension which is downloaded from the internet. There, rotating is working but there are some wired behaviours.

This is the extension code

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

    public func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat, flip: Bool) -> UIImage {

        let radiansToDegrees: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
            return $0 * (180.0 / CGFloat(M_PI));
        }
        let degreesToRadians: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
            return $0 / 180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI);
        }

        // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
        let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size));
        let t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(degrees));
        rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
        let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

        // Create the bitmap context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
        let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
        CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width / 2.0, rotatedSize.height / 2.0);

        // Rotate the image context
        CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, degreesToRadians(degrees));

        // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
        var yFlip: CGFloat;

        if(flip){
            yFlip = CGFloat(-1.0);
        } else {
            yFlip = CGFloat(1.0);
        }

        CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, yFlip, -1.0);
        CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-size.width / 2, -size.height / 2, size.width, size.height), CGImage);

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return newImage;
    }
}
```

This is how I call extension method and set returned image to the image view. image view's 'contentMode' property is set to 'Scale to Fill'

```
currentPagePreviewImageVew.image = currentPagePreviewImageVew.image!.imageRotatedByDegrees(90, flip: false);
```

This is how it looks before pressing rotate button

[image]

This is after pressing rotate button once.(See image is not rotated but it's size has been changed)

[image]

This is when the image rotation is 90 degrees.(Here after image is rotating but as you can see the other views get stretched when image is in 0 and 180 degrees as in the above screen(2))

[image]

Can some one please tell me what is wrong with my code and if there is a better solution please let me know. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Edited:** Stretching views was because of an constraint issue. I got it solved by putting a height constraint to the tool bar above the imageview. But still couldn't find an answer for that first time thing.

Comment: I had an issue because changing the affine transformation matrix had an effect on autolayout constraints, this may be a similar issue

Comment: @simpleBob What did you do to get your work done?

Comment: I removed and set the constraints again on the object

Comment: @simpleBob thanks man. I will try it.

Comment: @simpleBob Yes it was a constraint issue. But still having that first time thing. Thanks

Comment: Have you fix this problem? I have it too and want to fix it. Thanks

Comment: @LiborZapletal Yes. Will put it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below extension and it worked fine. This is **swift 3** actually.

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

    public func rotateImageByDegrees(_ degrees: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

        let degreesToRadians: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
            return $0 / 180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)
        }

        // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
        let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.size))
        let t = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degreesToRadians(degrees));
        rotatedViewBox.transform = t
        let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

        // Create the bitmap context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
        let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
        bitmap?.translateBy(x: rotatedSize.width / 2.0, y: rotatedSize.height / 2.0);

        // Rotate the image context
        bitmap?.rotate(by: degreesToRadians(degrees));

        // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
        bitmap?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        bitmap?.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: -self.size.width / 2, y: -self.size.height / 2, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))

        let cgimage:CGImage  = bitmap!.makeImage()!
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgimage)
    }
}
```

All the other things are same as in the question.

Comment: Thanks for update. I tried similar method before and it didn't help and same for this. It looks like when I try to rotate landscape photos than it works ok (even If I rotate photos to portrait and than again to landscape) but if I took photo as portrait and than try to rotate -> the first rotation deformates image and the other rotations are working ok but rotates with deformatted photo.

Comment: i have uiimageview than how can i use it.?

Comment: @MRizwan3395: You mean you wanna rotate UIImageView? Not image data? If you face a problem like this when you rotate an UIImageView, definitely it should be a constraint issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
    func flipImageVertical(originalImage: UIImage) -> UIImage
    {
        let tempImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: originalImage)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempImageView.frame.size)
        let context:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        let flipVertical:CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(1,0,0,-1,0,tempImageView.frame.size.height)
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical)
        tempImageView.layer .renderInContext(context)

        let flippedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return flippedImage
    }

    func flipImageHorizontal(originalImage: UIImage) -> UIImage
    {
        let tempImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: originalImage)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempImageView.frame.size)
        let context:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        let flipHorizontal:CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(-1,0,0,1,tempImageView.frame.size.width,0)

        CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipHorizontal)
        tempImageView.layer .renderInContext(context)

        let flippedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return flippedImage
    }
```

Comment: Your both methods are working fine. But this is not the thing that i wanted. I want to rotate the image. not flipping

Answer (score 1):

You must try this:

```
extension UIImage {
    public func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: Double, flip: Bool) -> UIImage {

        // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
        let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))
        let t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(toRadian(degrees)))
        rotatedViewBox.transform = t
        let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

        // Create the bitmap context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
        let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(bitmap, true)
        CGContextSetShouldAntialias(bitmap, true)
        CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmap, CGInterpolationQuality.High)

        // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
        CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width / 2.0, rotatedSize.height / 2.0)

        //   // Rotate the image context
        CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, CGFloat(toRadian(degrees)))

        // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
        var yFlip: CGFloat

        if(flip){
            yFlip = CGFloat(-1.0)
        } else {
            yFlip = CGFloat(1.0)
        }

        CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, yFlip, -1.0)
        CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-size.width / 2, -size.height / 2, size.width, size.height), CGImage)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage
    }
```

Then use this method to satisfy your new size:

```
extension UIImage {
    public func resizeImage(newSize:CGSize) -> UIImage {

        let newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
        let imageRef:CGImageRef = self.CGImage!

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0)
        let context:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
        CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, CGInterpolationQuality.High)
        CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true)
        CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true)

        let flipVertical:CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height)

        CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical)
        // Draw into the context; this scales the image
        CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef)

        // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
        let newImage:UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)!)

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return newImage
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping bro. But this didnt fix my issue.